# Matlab, Create one cell of some cells

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have 3 cell arrays of some strings  cell1, cell2 and cell3. I want to save them in one cell matrix.If the column size of each cell are col1 col2 and col3. I want to create one cell with size (max(col1,col2,col3)*3)).How can I?

```
cellmarix{:,1}=cell1;
cellmarix{:,2}=cell2;
cellmarix{:,3}=cell3;
```

but this created a cell of cells of size (1*3).

I also used

```
cellmatrix={cell1,cell2,cell3};
```

but the result was the same(1*3) cell of cells.

for example if I have

```
  cell1={
 'uzi'
 'julian'
 'ahyden'
 'kwayne'
 'riel'
 'gazook'
 'mustapha'
  }

cell2={
 'negro'
 'kris'
'sascha'
'jimw'
'andi'
'andrei'
 }

cell3={
'joncruz'
'youngsd'
'notzed'
'werner'
'cactus'
'Iain'
'faassen'
 }
```

The result is :

```
cell_all={
'uzi'        'negro'    'joncruz'
'julian'      'kris'    'youngsd'
'ahyden'      'sascha'  'notzed'
'kwayne'       jimw'    'werner'
'riel'        'andi'    'cactus'
'gazook'     'andrei'   'Iain'
'mustapha'      []      'faassen'
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explicit example please?

Comment: What about `cellmatrix={cell1;cell2;cell3}`?

Comment: @Dan that would produce a cell of cells, apparently that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @EitanT Thanks for comment. I add an example.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. I add an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
cell_all = cell1;
cell_all(1:numel(cell2), 2) = cell2;
cell_all(1:numel(cell3), 3) = cell3;
```

If you have a lot of cells (like you say you do), you can resort to a loop:

```
n = 3; %// Number of columns
cell_all = cell1;
for k = 2:n
    varname = sprintf('cell%d', k);
    cell_all(1:numel(eval(varname)), 2) = eval(varname);
end
```

This is one of those rare cases where [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) actually helps. However, I cannot help but wonder why there are so many cell variables in your workspace instead of populating one large cell array right from the start.

Comment: Thanks, But I have many number of cell.Is there any more efficient solution?

Comment: How many cells are we talking about? Why didn't you store their contents in one common cell array to begin with?

Comment: I need more general solution for huge matrices with more than 7000 columns.

Comment: @Fatime So you have 7000 different `cell` variables in your workspace?

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have about 7000 different cell variables.

Comment: @Fatime Wow, that's _a lot_ of variables. I've updated the solution, but perhaps you should consider rethinking your approach and generate one large common cell array from the start.

Answer (score 1):

```
C = {'one','two','three'};
str = strjoin(C)
```

--> see:

[TMW: join cell](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html?searchHighlight=join%20cell)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I explain my question better.Do you understand me?

Comment: I guess you are using an older version of matlab then I do-> try this:[strjoin](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31862-strjoin)